# Converting a matrix to the nearest positive definite matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition

I have a matrix 
$A = \begin{bmatrix}
 634.156 & 0 & 755912.06 \\
 0 & 1426.8604 & 598151.25\\
 755912.06 & 598151.25 & 1.1517e9\\
 \end{bmatrix}
$ with eigenvalues 
$\begin{bmatrix}
 1.15179e9\\
 1254.2858\\
 -1.52588e-5\\
\end{bmatrix}$. I want to calculate the Cholesky decomposition of the matrix A but A is not positive definite (the last eigenvalue of A is negative). How can I transform A into a nearest positive definite matrix inorder to calculate the Cholesky decomposition?

Comment: There is no nearest positive definite matrix.  At best you can find the nearest positive semidefinite matrix.  You might also reconsider your approach:  I assume this is coming up in a real world application, and you might throw away all meaning by performing this projection.  If you are sure this matrix should be positive definite for meaningful reasons, check where the numbers are coming from.

Comment: Another suggestion is to look at the space of eigenvectors with positive eigenvalues.  Is this space meaningful in your context?  Maybe you should really be restricting your analysis to this space>

Comment: Do you really need Cholesky?  For some applications an LDL decomposition would be just as good.

Comment: I am calculating homographies for image rectification. Theoretically this matrix should have been a positive definite matrix but due to noise it is not. I have checked my calculations and they seem to be correct to me. Since the eigenvalue is a very small negative number, I thought that something could be done to ensure that the matrix is positive definite?

Comment: Unfortunately, I only need Cholesky as it is part of the algorithm. Can't we force the last eigenvalue to be zero somehow?

Comment: Since the negative eigenvalue $\lambda_3$ is very small, the simplest thing to do might be just to add $\epsilon I$ to the matrix where $\epsilon + \lambda_3 > 0$.

Comment: What I've sometimes done was simply to do the Cholesky-algorithm and to truncate possible tiny negative eigenvalues to zero (but that was only possible because I myself had the hands on the programming of the Cholesky-routine...) and possibly Robert Israel's proposal is a better one.

Comment: Thank you for all the replies

Comment: I have no idea what exactly you are doing, but it is also worthwhile to perform some kind of analysis to see what the effect of having one very small positive eigenvalue will be.  If this is for image manipulation, I would guess that later computations might be numerically unstable, which may not have the desired effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ Muhammad Omer , if $A$ is your exact result (and not an approximation), then I think that your work is not serious for the following reasons:

1. The $a_{i,j}$ are known with $8,6$ or $5$ significant digits ; moreover the most important entry (considering the precision) is $a_{3,3}$ that is known with only $5$ digits.
2. The $<0$ eigenvalue of $A$ is $\approx -0.06$.
3. Since you know that the matrix is (in reality) SPD, then the principal question is: after a small modification of $A$, what will be the number of significant digits of the result $C$ s.t. $A=CC^T$ ?

For instance, if we replace $a_{3,3}$ with $1.151795$, then the $<0$ eigenvalue becomes $\approx 2.10^{-4}$. In other words, the digit $7$ is false and must be replaced with $8$ ; therefore, you have only $4$ significant digits. With this modified $A$ ($a_{3,3}=1.151795$), we obtain a matrix $C$ that can be written (with $10$ significant digits) $\begin{pmatrix}25.18245421& 0& 0\\0& 37.77380574& 0\\30017.41029& 15835.08038& 17.58435679\end{pmatrix}$ ; note that $||CC^T-A||\approx 0.37$, that implies that, if we keep $4$ digits for $C$, then  the error will be huge (cf. the Steven post: " later computations might be numerically unstable, which may not have the desired effects.").

Conclusion: in my opinion, $C$ is known with $0$ significant digit.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a square matrix there are several ways
to find the nearest symmetric positive semidefinite matrix outlined by
https://nhigham.com/2021/01/26/what-is-the-nearest-positive-semidefinite-matrix/

Then you can add a small perturbation learned from the eigenvalues to bring the final eigenvalues above 0 or a given machine precision or error level.
https://nhigham.com/2021/02/16/diagonally-perturbing-a-symmetric-matrix-to-make-it-positive-definite/

```
Here is pseudocode:

The simplest for an input symmetric matrix A is:

   set a machine precision or error level above 0:
       eps = 1.e-17 or 1.e-11 etc.

   get an orthogonal matrix from eigen decomposition of A:
       evd = EVD.factorize(A).
       leftEigenVec = evd.left;

   replace the eigenvalues smaller than eps with eps:
       tau = evd.realEigenvalues
       for (i = 0; i < tau.length; ++i)
           if (tau[i] < eps)
               tau[i] = eps;
   then the positive semidefinite matrix is   
       aPSD = leftEV * tau * leftEV^T
   
If you have a square matrix that is not necessarily symmetric:

   calculate B, the the symmetric part of A:
       B = 0.5*(A + A^T)
 
   calculate the polar decomposition of B to get Q and H 
   (where H is formed from V, S, and V^T of SVD(B) 
    within the polar decomposition method):
       [q, h] = polarDecomposition(b);

   the symmetric positive semidefinite matrix is then:
       aPSD = (A + h)/2

Then a small perturbation may need to be applied 
to result in eigenvalues greater than or equal to eps:
  evd = EVD.factorize(aPSD);
  eig = evd.realEigenvalues;
  if any eig < eps:
      sort(eig);
      eigMin = max(-eig[0], eps);
      eigMin = min(eigMin, 0)
      D = MatrixUtil.zeros(A.length, A.length);
      for (i = 0; i < eig.length; ++i)
          D[i][i] = eigMin;
      aPSD = aPSD + D;
```